# Recent chat should come first in quickblox history list

Tags: javascript, php, chat, desktop, quickblox

I want the recent message/chat with the counter should come first in the history list in Quickblox. How to configure this? Attached the screenshot. Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNDHY.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sort dialog list by message date sent

listdata is arraylist of QBChatDialog

```
Collections.sort(listdata, new Comparator<QBChatDialog>() {
                        public int compare(QBChatDialog o1, QBChatDialogo2) {

                            long valueA = ((QBChatDialog) o1).getLastMessageDateSent();
                            long valueB = ((QBChatDialog) o2).getLastMessageDateSent();

                            if (valueB < valueA) {
                                return -1;
                            } else {
                                return 1;
                            }

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use option in setting sort by date.
or use option desc order

Comment: Please elaborate. Where can I get this option? or do i need to do in my code?

Comment: Yeah! you can do this using code example.i have and query in mysql - 1. select * from users order by desc. 2. select username,created_date from users order by desc. 3. or asc.

Comment: I am not getting. Just to make sure I am using quickblox library.So please help me out how to update there because I am not getting any option.

Comment: examle : var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
use this -> fruits.sort();